# How to resolve ClassNotFoundException for AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

I'm practicing Spring framework. Below is my **dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yusmle.emusicstore"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.bind.support.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver" />
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

And below is my **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.yusmle</groupId>
    <artifactId>emusicstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.190</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm doing this according to a video course from Udemy, but I have this error while I'm trying to run on Tomcat server:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.bind.support.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.wrapWebArgumentResolverBeanDefs(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:522)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.getArgumentResolvers(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.bind.support.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:247)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:280)
    ... 67 more
...
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what tomcat are you starting. Is it a standalone or embedded tomcat? From your `pom` file I don't see that the project is built as a `war`. How are you deploying?

Comment: The class is in the `spring-security-web` jar. If the `jar` is in your classpath for Tomcat ( normally `WEB-INF/lib` ) - it should find it.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to put libraries into /WEB-INF/lib folder after I added `spring-security` dependencies to my `pom.xml` file. Also I changed version of my `spring-security` libraries to `3.5.2`, because it give me some other errors with new version `4.2.2`. Thanks for your comments, they really helped me. I use Intellij IDEA with standalone Tomcat I declared to it (for others that have problem like mine).

Comment: Also my error with `spring-security` version `4.2.2` is about (`BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]`), I think it's because of my other used libraries is deprecated! I used version `3.5.2` already (as used in video course) and I came back to it again.

Answer (score 1):

your spring core is *4.0.6.RELEASE* while spring security *4.2.2.RELEASE*

this means that spring-security sees spring core, asks spring-core.jar for class, but this class is not there yet (or anymore) because versions are different. this causes ClassNotFoundException

spring security core requires version of spring-core at least *4.3.5.RELEASE*

the solution is to unify versions and fix them, one by one for those that are missing.

to find what version you need, search (google it) for maven %artifact_id%, for example 'maven spring-security-core', find the artifact you need and scroll down to required dependencies. check that those that you include are version required or higher (usually higher versions are more-or-less compatible with previous, but lower versions rarely compatible with higher ones.

link to spring-security-core in maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/4.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: I saw your comment after I solve my problem(s)! My first problem was because of I forgot to put libraries into /WEB-INF/lib folder after I added `spring-security` dependencies to my `pom.xml` file. After I coudn't solve the problem, I tried to use newer versions of them! But you are right about difference of versions.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `maven` you don't have to put libraries to your `WEB-INF/lib` manually.

What you actually need to do is define your project packaging type as `war`:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

What it will do is when you run `mvn package` it will gather all your dependencies from your `pom.xml` and put it where they need to be in the `target` folder.

In your case you will find your packaged deployable files in `target/emusicstore-1.0-SNAPSHOT` folder which you can symlink, or reference in your `tomcat` application descriptor.